# Get remote endpoint IP with a WCF one-way contract

Tags: .net, wcf

In my (singleton) WCF service, I use the following to successfully get the IP of the remote (client) endpoint:

```
private String getRemoteIP()
{
    OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
    MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
    RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
    return endpoint.Address;
}
```

However, I have one procedure that is a one-way contract. This procedure returns an empty string when I run getRemoteIP - I'm assuming because the client endpoint is not relevant in a one-way call. Is there any way to get the client IP in such a case?